# Vue-cli не отображается компонент

Tags: javascript, vue.js, spa, vue-cli

Родительский компоент

```
<template>
  <div>
    <headerComponent></headerComponent>
    gg
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import Header from './template/header';
  export default{
    name:"Home",
    components:{ Header }
  }
</script>
```

Компонент который не работает

```
<template>
  <div>
    Шапка
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name:'headerComponent'
  }
</script>
```

Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option. found in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напиши вместо 'headerComponent' просто 'header'

Comment: но такой тег есть в html

Comment: components:{ headerComponent: Header }

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!! Убил на это пол вечера, ранее писал только на чистом js и очень непривычно писать теперь )